# 2 Different Aggregations in a Pivot

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have the pivot

```
PIVOT
    (
        MIN(DateId)
        FOR Stage IN
        (
            [Start], [Alpha], [Beta], [Release]
        )
    ) as p
```

I only want the MIN for the [Start] column and Max for every other column.
How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the entire query? I would suggest dumping that into a temp table (or whatever you like using) and then creating another pivot using the MAX(DateId) and simply joining them together. You can also use more columns by just creating another PIVOT http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/06/pivot-multiple-columns.html